# Error when using defining colour

Tags: color, packages

Currently I am using beamer slides how ever I found the template where I am understanding how we can write fonts with different colour but to define colour I have used the codes like this

```
\newcommand\red[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand\violet[1]{{\color{violet}#1}}
\newcommand\green[1]{{\color{OliveGreen}#1}}
\newcommand\blue[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
```

However I am getting the error when debugging the error I got to know that I have used a package

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
```

I don't want to remove this package can you please some one suggest me how I will not get any error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful to make your code snippet be compilable and please show us the first error you get. Copy and paste it into your question from the log file ...

Comment: you have not shown your code and have not shown the error message that you got but `usenames` and `dvipsnames` are options to the `color` package not the `pstricks` package.

Comment: I believe `usenames` is deprecated, but you may need to pass dvipsnames to beamer as `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}` instead to avoid a package option mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

May be it can help
site with colors http://latexcolor.com/

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\definecolor{camel}{rgb}{0.76, 0.6, 0.42}
\definecolor{applegreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\definecolor{brightgreen}{rgb}{0.4, 1.0, 0.0}


\newcommand{\bluetext}[1]{\textcolor{camel}{#1} }
\newcommand{\mycolor}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2} }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\bluetext{Here is example of colored text}\\
\mycolor{applegreen}{color - Applegreen}\\
\mycolor{aqua}{color - aqua}\\
\mycolor{apricot}{color - apricot}\\
\mycolor{aquamarine}{color - aquamarine}\\
\mycolor{brightgreen}{color - brightgreen}\\

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```